# Inverse of $L_1$-Norm

Tags: matrices

I have the following Equation:

$|x|_1=\eta$

where $x$ is a matrix and $\eta$ is a scalar value. How can I get the value of $x$?

Comment: norm is usually non-invertible. do you have special conditions on your matrix?

Comment: unfortunately, no. All what I know about this matrix is most of its entries are zeros